# Handling errors in a directory change

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a functionality of directory changes in my program, and i would like to handle the errors with errno.h.

```
int main(void)
{
    char directory[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]", directory);


    switch(chdir(directory))
        {
            case 0:
                printf("\nSuccess\n");
                break;

            case EACCES:
                perror("\nError ");
                break;

            case EIO:
                perror("\nError ");
                break;

            case ENAMETOOLONG:
                perror("\nError ");
                break;

            case ENOTDIR:
                perror("\nError ");
                break;

            case ENOENT: 
                perror("\nError ");
                break;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without errors and i was able to change the directory, so the `case 0` worked. But i was unable to get the other cases working when a error should appear.

On the man page of `chdir` it is said that on errors, `-1` is returned and errno is set appropriately. I tested on both Linux and Windows 7, still nothing.

Comment: *"...and `errno` is set appropriately."* - which none of your code actually checks. If you check the manual (always good), perhaps the code should reflect what it says about error detection.

Comment: From the man page for `chdir`:  "On  success,  zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately."  How is that not clear?  It returns -1 on error.  Not an error code.  It returns -1.  The error code is stored in `errno`.  I really don't see how it could possibly be any clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're stumbling on is the distinction between the return value and `errno`.  `errno` is a global variable, declared in `errno.h`.  What you want is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    char directory[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]", directory);

    if (chdir(directory) != 0) {
        switch (errno) {
          case EACCES:
            perror("\nError ");
            break;
          /*  ... */
        }
    }
}
```

It's also a bit weird that you have a bunch of cases in your switch that do the exact same thing… I'm assuming that's because they're just stubs and you really want to handle different errors differently in your code, but if not you can drop the switch and just do something like

```
if (chdir(directory) != 0) {
    perror("\nError ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```